# Toggle (slide) a hidden div with media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have here a content div `<div class="content">` that is hidden when going mobile using media queries, what I want to do is when pressing the head title `<div class="head">` to toggle (slide) the hidden content div.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="head">Head Title</div>
        <div class="content">Content Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="head">Head Title</div>
        <div class="content">Content Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="head">Head Title</div>
        <div class="content">Content Text</div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Responsive Media Queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
    .content { display: none; }
}
```

I tried this way with Javascript, but doesn't work:

```
$( ".head" ).click(function() {
$( "#content" ).toggle();
});
```

I can't make it work, I would appreciate some ideas, thanks!

Comment: @Regent yeah, I'm not a guru in JS, but I have added the method I tried.

Comment: I don't see any element with ID `content`. But I do see elements with class `content`. With `$('.content')` it works: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzurcdrL/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".head").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".content").toggle();
    });
});
```

In your code, you didn't get the "content" selector right: you're searching for an element with id="content" which isn't present in your HTML. The code above will realibly find & toggle the corresponding content element for a clicked head element as long as your HTML structure remains as is.

Comment: If you resize the browser to be smaller than the `560px` breakpoint, the `content` div disappears and you’re prompted with a head title to toggle it’s visibility. So far, this is the intended output. After toggling the `content` div, resize the browser back to the original state (larger than `560px`). At this point, you will notice the `content` div remains hidden and does not return to `display:block;`. Only after refreshing the browser will the `content` div re-appear. How can I make it when you resize the windows larger than `560px` the `content` divs are showing and not toggled hidden.

Comment: @ValeriCrudu This is happening since .toggle() will add an inline style attribute to your content divs which overrides anything declared within your .css file. Don't know if there's any clever way to avoid it, but I guess as a last resort you can always trigger on window.resize events to fix it: [hacky demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7h8euuj0/) .